# Python script in Abaqus raises "TypeError: keyword error on mergeWire"

Tags: python, robotics, abaqus

I'm new at Python scripting on Abaqus. I want to do fiber reinforced actuators which is described [here](http://softroboticstoolkit.com/book/fr-abaqus-step-1b) but I couldn't run the script properly. It gives me:

> TypeError: keyword error on mergeWire

[image: Screenshot of error message]

How can I fix this?  I'm using Abaqus Student Edition which is free.

Comment: don't ask  people to click on mystery links - post the relevant section of code where you use the offending keyword.

Comment: Unfortunately abaqus is prone to changing keywords with versions and that sort of thing pops up once in a while with older scripts. I would go through the exercise in the GUI and look at the code generated in the replay file, and/or review the scripting manual for your version for the `WireSpline` method syntax.

Comment: Also as a bit of a long shot be sure you haven't used the symbol  `OFF` as a variable for something else.

Comment: The documentation doesn't have mergeWire and meshable as options for WireSpline. As agentp says, abaqus scripting can change between versions. Instead try this: .....WireSpline(mergeType=SEPARATE,points=myPoints,smoothClosedSpline=OFF)

Comment: I believe there are two issues with that code: 1) abaqusConstants (which includes ON,OFF,..) is not imported; 2) WireSpline only has "points", "mergeType" and "smoothClosedspline" as arguments, so I'd investigate which type of merge you are after by looking at the documentation section 38.2.55 WireSpline()